# Fade in element on scroll down using css

Tags: jquery, css

Example: **http://www.chartjs.org/**

When scrolling down each article shows up when it gets in the view-port of the browser. The css is

```
#examples article {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

I tried this css but it does not work. Is there some javascript that works together with the css? How can I achieve this kind of scroll->fadeIn effect?

Comment: Try with [JQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/DFeqH/)

*Do you want something like this ?*

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.article').each(function (i) {

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);

            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Why define "i" but never use it?

Comment: Why guys if i scroll up and down at one moment the effect crash?

Comment: Hi @mohammad, thanx for this script. It works as expected but only one drawback I noticed, the divs show only after you have scrolled 3/4 of the viewport. Is there a way to make it show at a quarter of the viewport?

Comment: This only worked for me if I changed .position() to .offset()

Answer (score 6):

Mohammeds answer does not take into account any  absolutely positioned images... we should use offset instead of position

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.article').each(function (i) {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

            $(this).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 500);

         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I read it in the comments:

If you want the object to **fade in when 1/3** of the object is visible, then use this code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ($(this).outerHeight())/3;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        });

    });

});
```

Only line I changed, is this:

```
var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ($(this).outerHeight())/3;
```

By changing `/3` to e.g. `/4` you can let it fade in, when 1/4 of the object is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Best Process:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="monster">Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('.monster').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
#container
{
    height:2000px;    
}

#container DIV
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:pink; 
}

.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @K.H. thanx for this script. It works as expected but only one drawback I noticed, the divs show only after you have scrolled 3/4 of the viewport. Is there a way to make it show at a quarter of the viewport?