# jQuery fade element based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Based on this thread here:
[Fade in element on scroll down using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590236/fade-in-element-on-scroll-down-using-css/15590508#15590508)

I used the code in the accepted answer (with a slight change to how the animation runs) on a simple test page and it worked perfectly. When I moved the code into a more complex page, it isn't working right. All I changed between my two pages was the selector for the element I want to animate. After some digging, it appears it is getting the position of the desired element wrong. What is it about the content on the page that would throw off the math on the position? I can't link to my page, unfortunately, without some work, so if possible I'd like some possible suggestions before I do that.

Here is the JQ I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.fadein').each(function (i) {

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

                $(this).delay(90 * i).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 600);

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you using any JS plugins that could conflict with the jQuery `$` variable ?

Comment: I now have samples:

simple test:
http://tomliv.com/so-test/scrolltest.html

Problem page:
http://tomliv.com/so-test/about/

Comment: @tomliv Hardcode bottom_of_window = 1426. This will work until we change the logic.

Comment: We discovered this as well - we used 2000 - but the page is responsive and so at narrower widths hardcoding a height will fail as the page height will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, but I ended up replacing the above code with this:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

and it's working fine.

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The div was initially not visible.Check with

```
jQuery('.fadein').css('opacity');
```

when the page loaded(without scrolling). The opacity was ititially 0 and it was way down in the page and so it came to visible when you started scrolling. Will try to fix that in a few minutes.

Remove all **Position=relative**. It'll work.

Comment: Yes. The 3 icons with class of .fadein should be opacity=0 until their bottoms are above the bottom of the page, then the script will animate to opacity=1 in a sequential-type order. THis is the desired effect. Currently, they animate at ANY scrolling regardless of their position - including out of site off the bottom of the page.

Comment: @tomliv Its 0 in opacity initially and becomes the opacity becomes 1 when you start scrolling.

Comment: I think its getting the top positioning of its parent div

Comment: The position=relative was added as an attempt ti fix. Wasn't working without it either. Did you get it to work without?

Comment: I removed all position=relative in the css(i.e. from the parent divs) and its worked.

Comment: I don't mean to be thick-headed but this isn't having any effect on it for me. It's still not working.

Comment: For me when i remove all position=relative, the "bottom_of_object" is getting increased. Please check that once. I've checked in console.

Comment: I may at some point, but too busy right now. I have posted below that I am using an entirely different solution now. Also, removing position=relative *could* cause layout issues - especially in older browsers (like ie8) so I don't feel good about relying on that. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery in your .ready function, but $ inside. Try this to create a namespaced alias:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });
```

or the simplified

```
jQuery(function($){ ... });
```

Comment: I changed all to $ but still the same result. Thanks though.

I added test pages above.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. If anything, you'd change all $ to jQuery.

Comment: I changed

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

to

    $(document).ready(function(){

Thats not good?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Load is delays loading of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport are not loaded until user scrolls to them. This is opposite of image preloading.

Using Lazy Load on long web pages will make the page load faster. In some cases it can also help to reduce server load.

If you want to load images according to scroll i think this is what you want!

[LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: THanks. Lazy loading is good and we may add it, but what I am looking for is the animated effect, not just lazyloading.