# how to make this kind of displaying style

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-deployment

Have a look at [this](http://velikorodnov.com/themeforest/preview/?theme=CosyOne) website.As you scroll down the contents are displaying animated from left to right.What's the codes behind this?

This is a sample example

```
<div id="a"style="width:200px;height:400px">
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px"/>
</div>
<div id="b"style="width:200px;height:400px">
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px"/>
</div>
<div id="c"style="width:200px;height:400px">
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px"/>
</div>
<div id="d"style="width:100%;height:400px;display:none; ">
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px" style="float: left;"/>
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px"style="float: left;"/>
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px"style="float: left;"/>
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px" style="float: left;"/>
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px" style="float: left;"/>
<img src="home_v3_img_3.jpg" width="200px" height="400px" style="float: left;"/>

</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a combination of things happening, here is a summary:

They are listening for a change in scroll event on the window, and as the user scrolls down the page, add/change classes on various HTML elements. By adding or changing the classes, this triggers various CSS3 transitions such as opacity changes, position changes, etc. Some of these transitions happen in uniform, which is why the page appears to fade in elements from the left as you scroll the various contents into view.

Some helpful links / resources to accomplish this:

- Listen for the window scroll event, using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
- Fade in elements based on scroll position: [Fade in element on scroll down using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590236/fade-in-element-on-scroll-down-using-css)
- They are applying a transform transition to fade the elements in from the left. They are using transform: translateX([PX value]) to accomplish this. Here is the code from their CSS:

  ```
  .fadeInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeftBig {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
      transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your reply,Could you add apply that to the inserted code in the question,Please?